# Two methods to replicate a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, repeat, tiling

I found a simple way to replicate matrix dimensions but I do not understand it:

```
A=[1,2;3,4]  
A1=repmat(A,[1 1 2]);
```

returns

```
A1(:,:,1)=[1 2; 3 4 ]    
A1(:,:,2)=[1 2; 3 4]
```

And if I do this

```
A2=A(:,:,[1 1])
```

it returns exactly the same result. Please can someone explain how and why this second method works?

Comment: It seems I misread the question initially, have edited to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at a simpler example:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]*10;
```

Now I'm sure you'll agree that `A(1) = 10`, `A(2) = 20` etc but we can also address a matrix using a vector of indices e.g. `A([1,3])` returns `[10,30]` but you can also repeat indices and it will just address the same element twice: `A([1,1])` returns `[10,10]`.

Now lets add a dimension:

```
A = [1,2,3;
     4,5,6;
     7,8,9]*10;
```

So `A(1,:)` returns `[10,20,30]`. But what about A([1,1], :)? That's going to return the first row twice! So `[10,20,30;10,20,30]`

But what about the thrid dimension? `A` is a 3x3 2D matrix right? yes, but it's also a 3x3x1 3D matrix. So `A == A(:,:,1)`, which means that by the same logic as above `A(:,:,[1,1])` will just return that third dimension twice and hence is the same as `repmat(A, [1,1,2])`.